# Difference between svn checkout and svn update

Tags: svn, version-control

I have deployed an application using svn. Now that I have made some changes I wanted to run `svn update` in order to update my application.

After running `svn update` errors pop up. However when I remove all files  (including the `.svn` folder) and perform an `svn checkout [repourl]` there are no errors.

My question is what is the difference between `svn update` and `svn checkout [repourl]` in this situation? Why does a checkout of revision 100 work but an update from revision 50 to revision 100 product errors.

If you need additional information let me know, I've tried to keep it short.

I have looked at [Subversion - What are the differences between the SVN checkout and SVN update commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254552/subversion-what-are-the-differences-between-the-svn-checkout-and-svn-update-co) but this didn't help me find an answer.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: The errors are related to differing php versions. Shouldn't the errors be irrelevant since the errors are not present in a freshly checkedout version? (the php versions on the test location and live location are the same)

Comment: They sound even more relevant now; SVN has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Hmmm, at the end does this question have anything at all with _svn_?

Answer (score 2):

For better understanding, we can break [[RedBean.SVNBook]: svn checkout (co)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html) in 2 logical steps:

- Sets up (initializes) your *working copy* (*WC*): downloads from the server the ***SVN* metadata** (I'm going to explain below)
- Performs an *svn update* (*svn up*)

[[RedBean.SVNBook]: svn update (up)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html) downloads from the server (if not instructed otherwise) the latest state (called *revision* - which is a number that gets incremented by every modification) of the repository (based on the *SVN* metadata). It will also update the *SVN* metadata.

That's why *svn checkout* (*svn co*) is only used once (at the beginning), and from there subsequent *WC* updates are performed via *svn up*.

Since *svn co* creates (overwrites) the *SVN* metadata, and then updates the *WC*, it will **always** succeed, but since an external factor (the user) can mess up that metadata from the moment it's created, till *svn up* (or any other *svn* command as a matter of fact) takes place, *svn up* might fail.

*SVN* metadata:

- Located in the *.svn* folder under the root folder of your *WC* (older versions kept one such folder under every folder in the *WC* - which was messy). It's a **bad idea** to delete (or mess with) the *.svn* folder, basically your *WC* will become invalid; in such a situation a *svn co* is the only way to recover
- Contains data that *SVN* uses during various operations:

  - Server *URL* - when running a *svn* command that works with the server (e.g. *svn up*) you don't have to specify it (as for *svn co*) since it gets it from the metadata
  - Revision history - all the modifications that took place on every file / folder in the *WC*
  - Revision number - the last change / revision that was "downloaded" from the server (in the meantime the server could have advanced in revisions because other people made changes)
  - File / folder data - explained below

Your *WC* consists of a folder tree (contains folders and files). All that tree is also "replicated" in the *SVN* metadata (*.svn* folder) - that's why it takes up so much space. So, if you modify one of the source files in your *WC*, and then do a *svn status* (*svn st*) on it, *SVN* will detect the changes and *svn diff* will display them (in *diff* format) and this **without connecting to the *SVN* server**. Also, showing all the modification that a file suffered over time (*svn log*) doesn't need to connect to server.

I think it's clear now why *svn co* "always" succeeds. Regarding "*After running svn update errors pop up*", without details about the errors, I can't tell you more. Off the top of my head, I think of 2 situations that could lead to errors:

- You modified a file (or maybe more) in your *WC*. Someone else modified the same files (on the same lines roughly), and uploaded (*svn commit*) their changes to the *SVN* server. When you *svn up*, *SVN* doesn't know how to combine the changes (theirs and yours), so user intervention is required. This is **not an error**, but **a conflict** and happens frequently (if many people work on the same area), so it's perfectly normal. The conflict needs to be resolved (the 2 sets of changes merged together) making sure that both functionalities are preserved
- During a *SVN* operation (e.g. *svn up*), the *svn* process is abnormally terminated: e.g. <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl + Break</kbd>, the *WC* is left in an errorneous (*locked*) state. No further operations are allowed til it's brought back to normal (*svn cleanup*)